# Adding a Navigation Controller to a Tab Bar Application (Programmatically)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

This might look like a silly question to some, but handling the different types of controllers in an iPhone application is still a little fuzzy to me. Here's the setup:

I have a Tab Bar application with four tabs. Each tab passes control to its respective ViewController, where some of those are initialized with a .XIB file and some are done purely programmatically. One of the programmatic ones is `DirectionsViewController`, which is essentially a `UITableViewController`. Selecting a cell from its table needs to present (modally) a `DetailedDirectionsViewController`, which needs to have some sort of back-reference to the presenting view controller. I figured the easiest way to do this is to add a navigation controller to the `Directions` and `DetailedDirections` VCs - except I don't know how to do this without a .XIB file.

Also, the way I hand control over to `DetailedDirections` is by changing `Directions` the following way:

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    DetailedDirectionsViewController *vc = [[DetailedDirectionsViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    [self.tabBarController presentModalViewController:vc animated:YES];
}
```

I seem to recall one of my professors saying that `presentModalViewController` is kind of an old method and there are better alternatives... I just can't remember them right now.

Comment: Look at http://bit.ly/H4kHEZ and can look at sample code in that docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what you want to do it would be best to have the tab in your tabbar manage a UINavigationController, and to set the `rootViewController` of that navigation controller to your DirectionsViewController.

Then in your direction view controller's `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` methods you can do the following:

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    DetailedDirectionsViewController *vc = [[DetailedDirectionsViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
}
```

And it will function like you want it to.  The UINavigation controller will take care of putting a back button on your detailed directions view controller.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood well, in the tableview:didSelectRow..: you just need to create a navigation controller initializing it with the view controller that you want to display modally, before presenting it create a UIBarButtonItem and add it to the navigation bar of the navigation controller as selector create a new method with the dismiss command inside.